# What is an efficient way to do this in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

In R,
I am trying to filter out all cases from x whose $a is in y$b or y$d (when y$c is true).

```
x[(x$a %in% y$b | x$a %in% y[y$c == TRUE, ]$d), ]
```

Is this right? Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a logical column, no need to `== TRUE`.  Also, when subsetting a single column, directly subset instead of subsetting it from the data.frame which is inefficient

```
x[(x$a %in% y$b | x$a %in% y$d[y$c]), ]
```

Or make it a bit more compact

```
x[(x$a %in% c(y$b, y$d[y$c])),]
```

Comment: The compact alternative did not work because y$b and y$d[y$c] are factors, so I had to do: `x[(x$a %in% c(as.character(y$b), as.character(y$d[y$c]))),]`

Comment: @JuanPablo yes, I thought you had character columns.  You can convert the columns to charater i..e `x <- type.convert(x, as.is = TRUE)` and then use the same code

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth to give `subset` a try.

```
subset(x, a %in% b | a %in% y[y$c, 'd'])
```